# Filter the friend returned by FBFriendPickerViewController in new Facebook 3.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I have an Facebook app on http://developer.facebook.com of type "Native iOS" which is connected to the actual iOS app using the new Facebook iOS SDK 3.0.

How can I know if the multiple people that already install the the app and authorize the Facebook app too so I can put them in some list, but this not my question because I know that there is a field called "installed" that return `true` when the user install the app.

So if I want to filter the returned friend by the `FBFriendPickerViewController` based on if the user use the app, so how I can use the `installed` field or something else to filter the friends.

Note: I know where to filter the friend (*) all I need is the field or the property that I need to check to make sure the user is install my app.

*`- (BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
                 shouldIncludeUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this :

I create a method that send an FQL to those I need (for example my friends that they are male)

and then compare those returned by this request with the already exists by the `FBFriendPickerViewController` using the method :

`- (BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker shouldIncludeUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user`

for the request :

```
NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"query", @"q", nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:queryParam HTTPMethod:@"GET" 
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,  id result, NSError *error) {
             if (error)
             {
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"Some thing go wrong !, Try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                 [alert show];
             }
             else
             {
                 NSArray *friendInfo = (NSArray *) [result objectForKey:@"data"];

                 for(int i = 0; i < [friendInfo count]; i++)
                 {
                     [self.friendsNames addObject:[[friendInfo objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]];
                 }
             }     
 }];
```

As you see I have an `NSArray` that store the filtered friend, the next step is to compare them in the delegate method above.

Hope you find it useful.